# Is there any work that applies the approach in "Finite-Sample Convergence Rates for Q-Learning and Indirect Algorithms" to standard Q-learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, reference-request, papers, convergence

I am trying to mathematically characterize the finite sample convergence rates for Q-learning. To this end, I have read the following papers

- [Learning rates for Q-learning](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/evendar03a/evendar03a.pdf), by Eyal Even-Dar et al.;
- [The asymptotic convergence rate of Q-learning](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1997/file/cd0dce8fca267bf1fb86cf43e18d5598-Paper.pdf), by Cs. Szepesvari;
- [Finite-Sample Convergence Rates for Q-Learning and Indirect Algorithms](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/1998/file/99adff456950dd9629a5260c4de21858-Paper.pdf), by Kearns and Singh.

In the latter, they introduce a rather simple approach that seems appealing to me; however, they only sketch it for *phased Q-learning*.

I would be interested in knowing about any source where I could find the same approach modified for standard Q-learning; in section 4 of the paper, they claim that

> all of our results can be generalized to apply to standard Q-learning

Moreover, if you feel I am missing any paper that could be of interest with regards to the finite sample convergence of Q-learning, I would greatly appreciate it if you could post the name of it.